# Medium Style Header Effect - Full Screen Header

Tags: jquery, css, fullscreen

I'm seeing this effect on more and more websites and still can't quite wrap my head around how it is being done. I have used background-size:cover on a BODY or HTML element to create a full-screen background image - but I would love to be able to create a full screen header image that still has separate divs below it.

Here is an example:
https://medium.com/race-class/b84d4011d17e

I have tried this, but it only makes the div a few pixels high and does not cover the screen 100% vertically:

```
.header {
background: url(../images/header.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    height: inherit;
}
```

Here's a link to view it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8NdnP/